# ResponseEntity in Spring MVC for https

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, kubernetes, https

In Spring boot MVC application, in Controller class the ResponseEntity which returns file attachment and working fine. 
When I deploy this application in kubernetes with Ingress service enabled, the ResponseEntity returns Page Cannot be displayed message. Because the supported protocol is https whereas ResponseEntity supports http.

**How to get the same behavior in kubernetes as well?**

Code:

```java
    return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
               "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + \"").body(file);
```

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you give more context? Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: For Spring Boot see "server.forward-headers-strategy" (or "server.use-forward-headers" for Spring Boot < 2.2)